# Words ending in -cial/tial

Tags: word-formation

Can anyone please highlight the process behind the formation of words ending in `-cial`/`-tial`?

For instance,

> *finance* is the root for *finan**c**ial*

but,

> *different* is the root for *differen**t**ial*
>
> *substance* is the root for *substan**t**ial*

Is there some general rule to apply?

Comment: What about words like **partial** and **managerial** where the root is not changed by adding the *-ial* suffix?

Comment: @cobaltduck true, hadn't thought of those... I guess my question relates more to the **-cial** / **-tial** terminations. Fixed the question.

Comment: *Differential* is formed from *different*, not from *difference*.

Comment: There's a "sort of rule": [*Rule: Use -cial after a vowel, like after the vowel 'o' in social, 'e' in special, 'i' in beneficial. Use -tial after a consonant, especially, after 'n' in substantial, essential, and 'r' in parcial*](https://howtospell.co.uk/cial-and-tial-spelling-rules). But the final spelling mistake there is somewhat ironic, given the site is called ***howtospell.co.uk***

Comment: @Anonym my bad... I'll correct it. +1

Comment: I'm feeling quite stupid now, because I couldn't find the question marked as duplicate before asking this.

Comment: @Joum: I didn't find it either. But it's amusing to note that on the original, sumelic cited the same source as my comment above (***silently*** correcting the *parcial* spelling mistake! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: actually, it seems [the page I linked to](http://howtospell-letterpatterns.co.uk/cial-tial/) does not have the mistake, while [the one you linked to](https://howtospell.co.uk/cial-and-tial-spelling-rules) does. Mysterious! Perhaps one of the pages was edited at some point.

Comment: @sumelic: How odd. Actually, they seem to be two different sites, so it's tempting to suppose the "correct" one plagiarized and corrected the original.

Comment: @Joum I oversimplified in my comment. The word *substance* is from Latin *substantia*, whence *substantial*, The word *difference* is from Latin *differentia*, whence *differential*. As you can see, the change is actually not from *-c-* to *-t-*, but vice-versa; all these words came to us through Old French, which has a habit of changing things in ways that make very little sense to speakers of Modern English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: they're different sites, but they seem to be run by the same person, so I wouldn't call it plagiarism.